# $.change() won't detect all inputs changes with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a form with `id='from_name'` with inputs repeated with the same name:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control my-3" value="Name">
```

I have this name `name="name[]` repeated more than once.

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control my-3" value="Name">
.
.
.
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control my-3" value="Name">
```

`$('#from_name').change` will detect changes only for the first input with the same name, how can I detect all the changes that have been made to any input with the same `name="name[]`

```
name = []:
name = $('[name="device_id[]"]').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

The `name` array will return only the first input value not all changes inputs with the same name. When I change only the second input with the same name `name` won't return anything. What I'm missing?

Comment: i'd add the same class to all the elements you want to listen to the change event to and use that instead of the form id

Comment: Just change `$('from_name').change` to `$('[name="name[]"]').change...`

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks that's an easy solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use attribute selector with the name like `input[name="name[]"]` :

```
$('#from_name input[name="name[]"]').on('input', function(){
     //You code here
});
```

Like this, any input with the name `name[]` changed you will get the event fired.

**NOTE:**  I suggest the use of `input` instead of `change` event because it's more efficient when you track the user inputs.

```js
$('#from_name input[name="name[]"]').on('input', function() {
  var names = $('[name="name[]"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  console.log(names);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='from_name'>
  <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control my-3" value="Name">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control my-3" value="Name">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control my-3" value="Name">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control my-3" value="Name">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control my-3" value="Name">
</form>
```